# How to convert spark streaming output into dataframe or storing in table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

My code is:

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("hello" -> 5))
val data=lines.map(_._2)
data.print()
```

My output has 50 different values in a format as below

```
{"id:st04","data:26-02-2018 20:30:40","temp:30", "press:20"}
```

Can anyone help me in storing this data in a table form as

```
| id |date               |temp|press|   
|st01|26-02-2018 20:30:40| 30 |20   |  
|st01|26-02-2018 20:30:45| 80 |70   |
```

I will really appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use foreachRDD function, together with normal Dataset API:

```
data.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    // rdd is RDD[String]
    // foreachRDD is executed on the  driver, so you can use SparkSession here; spark is SparkSession, for Spark 1.x use SQLContext
    val df = spark.read.json(rdd); // or sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
    df.show(); 
    df.write.saveAsTable("here some unique table ID");
});
```

However, if you use Spark 2.x, I would suggest to use Structured Streaming:

```
val stream = spark.readStream.format("kafka").load()
val data = stream
            .selectExpr("cast(value as string) as value")
            .select(from_json(col("value"), schema))
data.writeStream.format("console").start();
```

You must manually specify schema, but it's quite simple :) Also import `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` before any processing

Comment: I cannot use spark.load.json. Even with SQLContext its giving error. I tried this                                                                                                     val sqlcontext=new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlcontext.implicits._
data.foreachRDD{ rdd=>
  val dfi=sqlcontext.load.json(rdd)   but it gives ambiguous reference to overloaded definition on sqlcontext.

Comment: @huny Which Spark version do you use? What is  the error? Generally, it should work. Maybe you have some edge case :)

Comment: I am using 2.10 version 1.5.1 of spark

Comment: @ T. Gawęda I have tried this, val res=rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("sensor") System.ln.print(res)..      there are no errors but its showing empty ()

Comment: @huny What error do you have with the solution from answer?

Comment: In spark.load.json(rdd)..cannot use spark here. With SQLContext it says load is not the value of SQLContext.. Then I tried val sqlcontext=new SQLContext(sc)     import sqlcontext.implicits._    data.foreachRDD{ rdd=>   val dfi=sqlcontext.load.json(rdd) but it gives ambiguous reference to overloaded definition on sqlcontext

Comment: Isnt it the same? Sorry if I can't notice it.. can you please mention it.

Comment: @huny  `spark.read.json(rdd);` instead of `spark.load` :) You can also `sqlContext.read.json(rdd)`

Comment: Thanks alot for your patience and answers. Finally solved :)

Comment: @huny Great it works :) Thanks for accepting, please also up vote if you can up vote answers :)