# how to run spark sql queries in every spark streaming batch?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

my scenario:

1. Create a spark streaming context to pull data from kafka for batch time 50 sec
2. create temp tables in spark for the data pulled.
3. run spark sql query on 50s batch temp table data

this must repeat till spark streaming job is running.

but i am unable to figure out a way where spark sql will be run within the streaming context.

As of now spark sql query is running only once and streaming is happening continuously.

```
val nv = (new Streamreader(kafkaParams,db))

  kafkaOpTopic.split(",").foreach(x => {
    nv.streader(ssc, Array(x))
  })
  spark.sql("show tables").show()
  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
```

StreamReader is doing kafka pull operation.

What would be the right way to run spark sql at the end of every spark streaming batch window ? how to realize it ?

Any idea would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert spark streaming output into dataframe or storing in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991745/how-to-convert-spark-streaming-output-into-dataframe-or-storing-in-table)

Comment: Don't know if should be marked as exact duplicate, but should help :)